# Using mclapply to return a vector instead of a list

Tags: r

I am currently trying to use mclapply within a function to create a function that simply takes all letters and turns them uppercase. However my output must be in a vector, and the only output I am getting is a list

```
library(parallel)


oneup <- function(x) toupper(x[1])

par_toupper <- function(cores) {
  mclapply(cores, oneup)
}
```

I am getting the correct output overall when testing and using my helper function (as required) oneup, but it returns a list and I need it to return a vector. Any easy adjustments I can make to my function?

Comment: You can use `unlist()` on the result and that should do the trick.

Comment: Alternatively use `mcmapply(oneup,cores,SIMPLIFY=T)`